# Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Network request failed - React Native

Tags: django, react-native

I can't communicate with my server.
I just getting an error like this on android

**Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Network request failed**

Comment: Please look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64394767/unable-to-connect-with-server-while-running-react-native-app-on-real-android-dev/64395715#64395715

Comment: Are you using ip address or domain for requesting?

Comment: Have you added  internet permission in AndroidManifest?

Comment: Where I can find this file?